# View-based NSTableView not applying partial reloads with DifferenceKit

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, nstableview

I'm using an NSTableView and DifferenceKit. This is all programmatic, no Interface Builder at all.

I'd previously implemented only `tableView(_:objectValueFor:row)` in order to get values into my table. At that point I could apply full and partial reloads and everything worked fine.

Now I've added an implementation of `tableView(_:viewFor:row:)` in order to format some columns differently, and it's affected reloading. A full `reloadData()` still works, but a call to `reloadData(forRowIndexes:columnIndexes)` doesn't call either my datasource or delegate methods; the reload seems to simply disappear.

I also tried removing the datasource method and running only with `tableView(_:viewFor:row:)` but no dice. A partial reload still doesn't call the delegate method.

Has anyone come across this? Is there a nuance of NSTableView I'm missing?

My code (truncated):

```
init() {
    ...
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self
    columns.forEach {
        tableView.addTableColumn($0)
    }
}

func tableView(
    _ tableView: NSTableView,
    objectValueFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?,
    row: Int
) -> Any? {
    ...
    return someStringProvider(column, row)
}

func tableView(
    _ tableView: NSTableView,
    viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?,
    row: Int
) -> NSView? {
    ...
    if let existingView = tableView.makeView(withIdentifier: identifier, owner: self) as? NSTableCellView {
        existingView.textField?.stringValue = someStringProvider(column, row)
        return existingView
    }

    let textField = NSTextField()
    ...
    textField.stringValue = someStringProvider(column, row)

    let view = NSTableCellView()
    view.identifier = identifier
    view.addSubview(textField)
    view.textField = textField

    view.addConstraints([
        ... (pin textField to view)
    ])

    textField.bind(
        .value,
        to: view,
        withKeyPath: "objectValue",
        options: nil
    )

    return view
}
```

Comment: I tried your code, `tableView(_:objectValueFor:row)` and `tableView(_:viewFor:row:)` are called. Post a [mre] please.

Comment: Thank you @Willeke, I've just gotten to the bottom of this and DifferenceKit turned out to be much more relevant than I had assumed. I'll alter the question somewhat for anyone who happens upon it later.

Answer (score 0):

This turns out to be either a misunderstanding of, or possibly a bug in, the way DifferenceKit interacts with a view-based, rather than cell-based, NSTableView.

I was crucially not checking the *values* with which `reloadData(forRowIndexes:columnIndexes)` was called, and the columnIndexes passed by DifferenceKit's algorithm were always `[0]`, which was not valid for any visible cells as my first column is hidden, so the methods weren't called.

The useful lesson here is that when a tableview's delegate lacks `tableView(_:viewFor:row:)`, a reload to *any* column reloads the entire row, but once views are specified, the column values become relevant.

Comment: What is objectValue-based `NSTableView`? Both cell based and view based `NSTableView` can be objectValue-based. It looks like your table view was cell based before `tableView(_:viewFor:row:)` was implemented. The cell based table view does not reload the entire row but reloads another column if the specified column is hidden.

Comment: Sorry, yes, your terminology is correct.